# What is the difference between "RAID10" and "RAID1 (With more than 2 disks)"?

Tags: linux, raid

What is the difference between "RAID10" and "RAID1 (With more than 2 disks)" ?

Comment: Running a Linux MD RAID for 2-3 disks also is a great idea for cost vs performance.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) explains it pretty solid. Here are two pictures which show the difference:

> RAID 1 comprises mirroring (without parity or striping). Data are written identically to two (or more) drives, thereby producing a "mirrored set". The read request is serviced by any of the drives containing the requested data. This can improve performance if data is read from the disk with the least seek latency and rotational latency. Conversely, write performance can be degraded because all drives must be updated; thus the write performance is determined by the slowest drive. The array continues to operate as long as at least one drive is functioning.

[image]

> RAID 1+0: creates a striped set from a series of mirrored drives. The array can sustain multiple drive losses so long as no mirror loses all its drives.

[image]